# Using a column data source how can I get a row's index?

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I'm using pandas data frame which is populated from a CSV file, then I use Bokeh to convert that data frame into a ColumnDataSource.

Which looks like:

```
dataFrame = pandas.read_csv('somefile.CSV')
source = ColumnDataSource(dataFrame)
```

Now that I have all my columns, I want to do row-based calculations.

For example: I have three columns:

```
x, y, colour
```

it might be populated with:

```
1, 2, blue
2, 5, red
1, 8, yellow
```

Now, I want to change some associated variable, in that row, when I search through the source, so how can I do this:

```
# how do i step through the source dictionary?
if source['colour'] == 'blue':
    # how do I get the current index, which is the row number
    # how do I change the x column value at the index(row) we retrieved
    source['x' index] = 2
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are iterating through the data you can do it this way:

```
dataFrame = pandas.read_csv('somefile.csv')
source = ColumnDataSource(dataFrame)

for index, colour in enumerate(source.data['colour']):
    if colour == 'blue':
        source.data['x'][index] = 2
```

Alternatively, to avoid iterating through the entire ColumnDataSource you can get the index of the first value of `'blue'` in the `'colour'` column using this:

```
list(source.data['colour']).index('blue')
```

You can use this as the index for editing column `x` like this:

```
source.data['x'][list(source.data['colour']).index('blue')] = 2
```

Indexing this list this way will just give you the first index of the value `'blue'`. If you have more than one occurrence of `'blue'` in your ColumnDataSource for which the associated `'x'` value should be edited you should be able to iterate through the `'colour'` column by indexing the list starting just after the last index of `'blue'`:

```
list(source.data['colour'])[last_index+1:].index('blue')
```

The loop that this is in should be wrapped in a try-statement as `index('blue')` throws a `ValueError` when the list it is searching does not contain the value `'blue'`.

Comment: Thanks, I found I can get dataFrame.iloc[index] as well which returns the row! If anyone knows any faster ways to do this, please let me know as both the above method and my method are super slow on large data sets.

Comment: If you only need to make the changes initially (before it goes into the ColumnDataSource) then making those changes in the pandas dataFrame will almost certainly be the fastest. You can also do: `df['x'].loc[(df['colour'] == 'blue')] = 2`. This should still be extremely fast even on large data sets.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
source.x[source.color == 'blue'] = 2
```

`source.x` is the series which you want to change, condition in brackets select only rows for which it is true.